# How templates get rendered when using directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I am using AngularJs for many projects every time I work in a new project I try to make it more reusable and structured and separate the project into small components (directives,providers,factories and templates)

**The issue :** In many cases  I need to run some DOM manipulation but it doesn't work  as expected  because the JS function run before the DOM is ready

**Example**

**app.js**

```
angular.module('App',['ngRoute']);
```

**route.js**

```
angular.module('App').config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'templates/homeTemplate.html'
    })
    .when('/new',{
        templateUrl:'templates/brand/newTemplate.html'
    })
})
```

**directive.js**

```
 /*
 * AngularJs Directive: fcNew
 * Depencies:
 * Desc: load user widget template
 */
 angular.module('App').directive('fcNew',function($http){
   return{
    templateUrl:'templates/userWidgetTemplate.html',
    replace:true,
    link:function(scope,ele,attr){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:"/user-side-bar"
        }).success(function (res) {
            scope.links= res;
        })
    }

   }
 })
```

**userWidgetTemplate.html**

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-repeat="link in links">
                <a href="#">{{link}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

**newTemplate.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <fc-new></fc-new>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FansCoupon">
<head>
    <title>Laravel</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default fc-navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I navigate to `#/new` only the collapsing menu in the index (outside ng-view) is working but the collapse inside the directive template not working when I try to log the selector `.dropdown-toggle` only one element is found which mean the DOM wasn't ready when the function is called

If it possible I need to understand how the directive render the templates and when or in another words where can I put my code to manipulate the dynamically created DOMs using directive templates?

**Note:** I am using [boostrapJs without jQuery](https://github.com/tagawa/bootstrap-without-jquery) it works great but without using directive templates

**Note:** I am using gulp task runner to concat all files in one file called `scripts.js`

the issue in a picture [image]

the menu in red (outside the ng-view)is collapsing
the menu in white (rendered from direcctive template) not working

I am very sorry for the long post , thanks in advance!

Comment: it seems to me you should use a resolve in your routing config

Comment: @Slip Thanks for your reply, Could you please explain a little?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it but I don't know if this is the best practice or not

I used `$locationStartSuccess` and wrapped the scripts I was using in a function called  `bootstrap_without_jquery` and I called it on `document.ready` now it works :

```
angular.module('App',['ngRoute']).run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(next, current) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){

        bootstrap_without_jquery();
    });

  });
})
```